# Auto-py-to-exe [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python, exe

I'm trying to build an .exe from my .py, the following error comes up:

```
File "distributed\config.py", line 17, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\MTEICH~1\AppData\\Local\Temp\\\_MEI304202\distributed\\distributed.yaml'.
```

Comment: Nobody can help?! :-(

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and I solved it as follows:

Go to c:/ drive and search "distributed.yaml" it is located probably in "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\distributed".
You should copy this folder "distributed" to where your exe file is located.